# How will "One to many" relation in the same table will be mapped?

Tags: asp.net, sql, orm, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a table that has a one to many relation within the same table.

**Directory**

```
DirID int PK

ParentID int FK
```

When I try to map(ORM) it using ado.net  entity data model, I got the following:

**Directory**

```
DirID int 

ParentID int 

Directory1 collection<Directory>

Directory2 Directory
```

Why I can't get a list of directories in "ParentID" .. just like the result I can get mapping two tables(with one to many relation between them)? and what that Directory2 reference is for?

Answer (score 1):

`Directory1` is the collection of children.  `Directory2` is a reference to the parent.

Comment: Why I don't get the collection of children in ParentID ?

Comment: ParentId and DirId are integer properties that directly map to the columns in the database.  The Directory1 and Directory2 properties are created by the ORM layer to allow easy traversing of the object model.